# How to make `all_done` trigger rule work with *-grandparent nodes in airflow 1.8?

Tags: airflow

The trigger rule "all_done" is not working when its parents are marked as `State.None` instead of `State.Upstream_Failed`.

The problem as I understand it is that tasks downstream from a failed task are never queued and thus their state stays `None` forever.

Here is a partial treeview of my DAG which I believe demonstrates the issue:

[image: treeview]

In this DAG `tmp_cleanup` is set to `all_done` because we want to cleanup whether things fail or not. This works if an immediate parent fails (`load_att_wv2_m1bs`), but not if a *-grandparent fails (`rm_spurrious_gis_files` or `unzip_wv2_ingest`) because `UPSTREAM_FAILED` never propagates.

[AIRFLOW-1515](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1515?attachmentSortBy=dateTime) reports this as a bug, giving me the impression that `all_done` does not work for *-grandparents in `1.8`.

If this cannot be fixed through a change in configuration, I want to know the best way to recreate the behavior of `all_done` so that I can run a cleanup task at the end of a DAG regardless of whether it fails or succeeds.

Comment: Cron jobs would be a way to go if Its a bug

Comment: The problem with a cron job (or an independent DAG) in this case is that I don't want to clean up the files in the middle of processing. A lock file might work to solve that issue, but then we come back around to my initial problem of needing to do something (rm lockfile) at the end of a DAG.